# How to solve timezone conversion error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert to a swedish timezone with this code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
TimeZoneInfo cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local);


var swedishTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDate, cet, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

For some reason I am getting:

> {"The conversion could not be completed because the supplied DateTime
>   did not have the Kind property set correctly. For example, when the
>   Kind property is DateTimeKind.Local, the source time zone must be
>   TimeZoneInfo.Local.\r\nParameter name: sourceTimeZone"}

What am i missing?

Comment: Use the proper type, DateTimeOffset. You can't avoid conversion errors with `DateTime` alone, even if it's set to `DateTimeKind.UTC`. Eg Local - to what? The web application, the server or the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

- Culture only affects output formatting when converting to/from strings.  It doesn't affect time zone conversions, so it is unnecessary here.
- The time zone identifiers used by `TimeZoneInfo` on Windows come from the Windows operating system itself, and sometimes their names do not match up to what you may expect.

  - You're using the Windows time zone ID `"Central European Standard Time"`, which has a display name of `"(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb"`.
  - For Sweden, you should actually use the ID `"W. Europe Standard Time"`, which has a display name of `"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"`
  - You can read more about this in the section titled *"The Microsoft Windows Time Zone Database"* in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- Since it appears you are looking for the current time in a particular time zone, you should not be going through the local time zone at all.  Just convert directly from UTC to the target time zone.

The code should simply be:

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");
var swedishTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.UtcNow, tz);
```

Or if you prefer, you can use a convenience method:

```
var swedishTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                                 "W. Europe Standard Time")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just delete "TimeZoneInfo.Local" from "var swedishTime".

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
TimeZoneInfo cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Local);


var swedishTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentDate, cet);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it by changing to `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.

Instead of this

```
var currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

I put this:

```
var currentDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
```